# EntityFramework ignore login name in connectionString

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

Hi iam trying to configure my first application with EF but find no way to connect to DB

this is my context

```
public partial class FunzionamentoContext : DbContext
{
    public FunzionamentoContext()
        : base("FunzionamentoContext")
    {}

    static FunzionamentoContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<FunzionamentoContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Controllo> Controllo { get; set; }
}
```

this is connection string (present in app.config file of DAL project since i still don't have UI project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FunzionamentoContext"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            connectionString="Data Source=xyzxyz; Initial Catalog=dbName;
        Integrated Security=false;User ID=test;Password=test" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

this is a simply method i make to test connection (only for search if connection is done, next i will rewrite it in a more beautyful way :D)

```
    [Test]
    public void TestTrue()
    {
        FunzionamentoContext fctx = new FunzionamentoContext();
        Controllo c = new Controllo();
        .id = 1
        fctx.Controllo.Add((Controllo)c);
        fctx.SaveChanges(); 
    }
```

When i try to connect i see this error:

FunzIA.UnitTest.DAL.TestFixture1.TestTrue:
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException : The underlying provider failed on Open.
  ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot open database "FunzionamentoContext" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\U123456'.

where DOMAIN\U123456 is my windows account

Why EF use my windows account and not the one wrote in connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you have your DAL in a separate project from the project you're actually running.

Your application will use the config file from the project you're trying to run, and not the one directly related to the DAL project.

By this, I mean, if you're only using the test project (assuming it's in a different project from the DAL) then you need the connection string in the app.config of your test project.

Comment: I assume this to be the case as well. If no connection string is found, EF will try to connect to your local SQL Server using Windows Authentication.

Comment: Yes, but because he has supplied a connection string name, in `base()` (`FunzionamentoContext `) then EF will only use that, and not look any further

Comment: Replace "FunzionamentoContext" in connection string name with its full namespace.

Comment: yes, adding connection string in test project the connection work. iam interested in Andrew suggestion but need few more explanation: so it's possible to say test project where is the correct config file?

Comment: Yep, if your DAL project namespace is `MyProject` you should be able to put `MyProject.FunzionamentoContext` as the name (if memory serves...) - I tend to steer away from this as I like the project i'm running to set the DB - you may, one day, have multiple projects using your DAL project and want different DB's

Comment: Interesting, maybe go into it when I start to seriously test my DAL project