# All DbSets are empty?

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-connection, connection-string, entity-framework-6

In my solution I got a DataAccess project which has the following connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LM.DataAccess.mdf;Initial Catalog=LM.DataAccess;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

It has a repository which can access the database just fine WHEN being run by the DataAccess project itself.

I'm trying to access the repository from another project in the solution - however whenever I'm in the repository (from running this project) all the dbsets on the dbcontext are empty.

What could be the reason of this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EntityFramework ignore login name in connectionString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988541/entityframework-ignore-login-name-in-connectionstring)

Comment: `|DataDirectory|` will point to different folders for different EntryPoint projects.